# Re-direct URLs in Salesforce 1

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning, salesforce1-app

We have been using "PageReference" method in controller to re-direct urls in Classic, Salesforce 1 and Lightning. But Salesforce no longer supports "PageReference" for Salesforce 1 and Lightning.

So which method or how do I re-direct URLs in Salesforce 1 and Lightning ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the "Manage Navigation" unit in the "Visualforce & Lightning Experience" trailhead module:

> “Classic” Visualforce navigation can be boiled down to “what happens at the end of an action method.” Action methods return a PageReference object with the details of where the user is to be navigated to, and then the Visualforce framework handles the details of sending the right response back to the user’s browser. And, great news, all of this still works.
>
> Remember also that the Standard Controller returns a PageReference from its action methods. So, your existing navigation, whether you’re using the Standard Controller or your own custom controller code, continues to work as you expect.